# Is Miki compelled by a Governor Module or other programming, or does it have freedom of choice?

Tags: murderbot

In *Rogue Protocol: The Murderbot Diaries* we meet a third type of anthropomorphic robot, the human-form bot named Miki:

> There was also a human-form bot standing nearby.  I hadn't seen one in
> a while in person, just on the entertainment feed.... Unlike
> constructs, they don't have any cloned human tissue, so they're just a
> bare metal bot-body that can pick up heavy things, except not as well
> as a hauler bot or any other kind of cargo lifter.

The other kinds of anthropomorphic robot we meet in the *Murderbot Diaries* (SecUnits and ComfortUnits ("Sexbots")) are restricted by way of a Governor Module, and don't have the ability to disobey orders from owners or whoever is paying for them at any given time.

At the climax of the story, Miki fights to protect its owner, **rejecting orders to do otherwise**:

> In the feed, Abene yelled at Miki to come in with them, she would tell
> Kader to open that hatch if it would just come in - and Miki told her,
> *Priority is to protect my friends*.
>
> *Priority change*, Abene sent.  *Priority is to protect yourself*.
>
> *That priority change is rejected*, Miki told her.

The fact that Abene has a directive phrase ("Priority change") implies that Miki is also restricted in some way to carry out the instructions of its owner.  But Miki's behavior suggests it is able to choose its actions despite its programming.

**The question:** Are there any other interactions in *Rogue Protocol* between Miki and the humans that involve Miki disobeying Abene or her friends, or that violate *Priority is to protect my friends*?  Is there any explicit evidence for or against Miki having a Governor Module or programming equivalent?

(Note that the security consultants, Wilken and Gerth, are not Miki's friends.)

Answer (score 2):

Bots don't have governors.  From *Fugitive Telemetry*:

> The supervisor hesitated, nodded, and then continued on down a corridor. I don't know what they think I'm going to do to their bots. Teach them to hack? **Bots don't have governor modules like constructs** and it's not like the Preservation bots weren't supposedly able to do whatever they wanted.

There's another bit further on in *Rogue Protocol* where Murderbot is reflecting on how Miki got itself killed:

> Abene had tried to change Miki's priority to saving its own life, and it
> had refused her. Which meant **she had allowed its programming that option,
> that ability to use its own judgment** in a crisis situation.

So Miki doesn't have a governor and its programming was flexible enough to allow it to reject commands in at least certain circumstances.